# Getting values generated by method on demand

Tags: python-3.x

I'm working with an API which is similar to this:

```
class API:
    def start(self):
        self._calculate(100)

    def _calculate(self, n):
        # do some calculation
        for i in range(n):
            self.on_value_calculated(i**2)

    def on_value_calculated(self, x):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

`start` is a public method, `on_value_calculated` is an abstract method and `calculate` is a protected method. In order to get the values calculated by the API, I should create a new class inheriting from `API` and overriding `on_value_calculated`, so:

```
class MyAPI(API):
    def on_value_calculated(self, x):
        print(x)
```

My question is: in the code above, when I run `start` method, all the 100 iterations are called one after another. How can I get the calculated values on demand, like in the pseudocode below?

```
api = MyAPI()
api.start()

def get_next():
    item = next(api)
    label.set_text(item.text)
    print('Another item generated!')

button.set_command(get_next)
```

I thought of using `yield from` in `start` and `yield` in `on_value_calculated`:

```
def get_next():
    item = yield from api.start()
    label.set_text(item.text)

class MyAPI(API):
    def on_value_calculated(self, x):
        yield x
```

But it raises `NoneType is not an iterable`.

I could implement `__next__` method, but I don't think there is a way to send the value calculated to the `__next__` return value. The reason I want on demand is because the values calculated uses some memory, and having a list of them could make the program slower.

Thanks for any help!